# How generic/specific should HTML5 web components created with vanilla JavaScript be?

Tags: javascript, css, html, web-component, custom-element

I am designing a web application using HTML5 web components (HTML imports, shadow DOM, templates and custom HTML elements) implemented with vanilla JavaScript (no framework). The web application is reasonably simple, and must be implemented as a single-page application. Part of the requirements of the application is that the user-interface should be customisable.

**Design Approach**

The example uses an `<application-navigation>` custom element. This element communicates with the "top-level" JavaScript (e.g., a "router" in JavaScript MV* parlance) via custom events (e.g., `new CustomEvent('application-navigation', {location:'/sign-in'})`) and method calls (e.g., `document.querySelector('application-navigation').enableSignOut()`). In essence, the custom events and methods form the element's "public API".

A customised `<application-navigation>` element can be included in the application using a different HTML import. E.g., using `<link rel="import" href="default/application-navigation.html"/>` or `<link rel="import" href="my_cool_theme/application-navigation.html"/>`. As long as the HTML import has the same methods and produces the same custom events, the application should function identically regardless of what user-interface customisation is being used.

The main benefit of this design is that it meets the requirements by allowing a very customisable user-interface - the internal JavaScript events, CSS and (shadow) DOM structure can be complete different between templates. It also allows reuse of existing libraries if and where appropriate. For example, the default `<application-navigation>` element could use the dropdown HTML markup from Twitter Bootstrap, while a themed version could use the Foundation library.

However, this component is not very generic. It fulfils a rather specific purpose (controlling navigation requests), unlike, for example, an `<application-dropdown>` element (although the `<application-navigation>` element could make use of a (customisable) `<application-dropdown>` element).

**Restating the Question**

My question is, should custom elements be created to fulfil a *specific* purpose, a more *generic* purpose, or is the breadth of purpose irrelevant?

Answer (score 1):

You can build either specific or generic custom elements. Both are relevant.

However, the main benefit of defining custom elements is the ability to *reuse* them easily. So I would say a custom element is often *generic*.

Regarding architecture, you can design generic *technical* elements, then with them you can compose specific *functional* elements.

---

Anyway creating 2 different components with the same tag name is not a good idea. You'd rather use another approach to achieve your goal (use attributes or inner elements to customize your custom element, or give it another name).

Here is an exemple with a theme defined as an element attribute:

```js
//CUSTOM ELEMENT
var proto = Object.create( HTMLElement.prototype )

proto.createdCallback = function ()
{
  console.log( "{created}" )
  var html = document.querySelector( "template" )
  this.innerHTML = html.innerHTML
}

proto.attributeChangedCallback = function ( attr, old, val )
{
  console.log( "{changed} attr=%s, old=%s, new=%s", attr, old, val )
}

var AN = document.registerElement( "application-navigation", { 
  prototype: proto 
} )

//EVENTS
function add ()
{
  if ( AN )
    document.body.appendChild( new AN )
}

function theme ( name )
{
  var elem = document.querySelector( "application-navigation" )
  if ( elem )
    elem.setAttribute( "theme", name )
    }

function load ()
{
  var link = document.createElement( "link" )
  link.rel = "stylesheet"
  link.href = "/content/green.css"
  document.head.appendChild( link )
}
```

```css
application-navigation[theme=blue] {
   color: blue ;
  }
  application-navigation[theme=red] {
   color: red ;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <nav>
  <button onclick="add()">Add Custom Element</button>
  <button onclick="theme('red')">Change First to Red</button>
  <button onclick="load()">External CSS</button>
 </nav>
 <template>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <p>Custom Element Content</p>
 </template>

 <application-navigation theme="blue"></application-navigation>
</body>
</html>
```

In the example above you can even load an external CSS file whose relative URL is `/content/green.css`:

```
application-navigation[theme=blue] * {
    color: limegreen ;
}

application-navigation[theme=red] p {
    color: green ;
}

application-navigation[theme=red] h1 {
    color: orange ;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any links with examples of such customisation?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an exemple of such customization.